# weblogic security realm export via wlst

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic11g, wlst

Just trying to export the default weblogic security realm via wlst, same function as in gui via Security Realms > myrealm > Migration > Export/Import. When I do it via the gui it creates a file called

```
exportIndex.dat
```

Just wondering if this is metadata for the gui only? Does anyone know? Can't find much info about this file from the docs. Also can't find the path-to-MBean/mbeanname for it here:

`('DomainServices/DomainRuntimeService/DomainConfiguration/mydomain
/SecurityConfiguration/mydomain/DefaultRealm/myrealm/..path-to-MBean/mbeanname..')`The other 4 files i can import/export via wlst by cding to correct realm path. These guys I can import/export just fine:

```
DefaultAuthenticator.dat
XACMLRoleMapper.dat
XACMLAuthorizer.dat
DefaultCredentialMapper.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

You will find your answers in this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13707/security_data_migration.htm#SECMG325)

Comment: No I won't. I've gone over that document several times. My question is not a "how to" it's a "what the hell is this and why is it here"... There's an extra file that gets created when u do migrate>export through the gui i can't find the corresponding path-to-MBean/mbeanname for it... Looks like metadata and nothing about it in the docs

Comment: Here is an example, i hope it will help you : `domainRuntime() 
 cd('/DomainServices/DomainRuntimeService/DomainConfiguration/wls1213SPDomain/SecurityConfiguration/wls1213SPDomain/DefaultRealm/myrealm/AuthenticationProviders/DefaultAuthenticator')   cmo.exportData("DefaultAtn",'d:\\data.xml',None)`

Comment: Right, that's the mbean for hte DefaultAuthenticator... I can tell you the other 3: myrealm/RoleMappers/XACMLRoleMapper, myrealm/Authorizers/XACMLAuthorizer, myrealm/CredentialMappers/DefaultCredentialMapper ....... That doesn't help me answer the question, where is the mbean for `exportIndex.dat` where does this file come from and what is it for?